# send data from stage to multi column table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have an internal named stage where json files are stored and from there I want to store them in snowflake table. The structure of destination table is as follows,

```
file_name (string)
load_date (timestamp)
data      (variant)
```

I am using the following query to move the data from stage to table

```
copy into tableName (data) from @stagename/filename.json;
```

But the above query is only populating the data column, what I want is to insert the timestamp and filename too. Any idea what changes I need to make in the query? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `COPY` statement with a transformation - documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html#transforming-data-during-a-load). When you use that method you can query the metadata of the files to get the filename, row number etc - documentation for that [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html#querying-metadata-for-staged-files).

**Example file `filename.json` uploaded to an internal stage called `stagename`:**

```
[{"name": "simon"},{"name": "jason"}, {"name": "jessica"}]
```

**Sql to load create and load table:**

```sql
-- Create example table first with 3 columns
create or replace transient table test_table
(
    file_name varchar,
    load_date timestamp,
    data      variant
);


-- Load with transformation: 
copy into test_table (file_name, load_date, data) from (
    select
        metadata$filename,
        current_timestamp,
        f.$1
    from @stagename/filename.json f
)
    file_format = (
        type = json
            strip_outer_array = true
        )
    force=true
;
```

**Results:**

```
+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+
|FILE_NAME    |LOAD_DATE                    |DATA                   |
+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+
|filename.json|2021-07-16 08:56:24.075000000|{"name": "simon"}      |
|filename.json|2021-07-16 08:56:24.075000000|{"name": "jason"}      |
|filename.json|2021-07-16 08:56:24.075000000|{"name": "jessica"}    |
+-------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Simon. I am using your above copy into query with my own column and table name but I am getting the following message as the result.
Copy executed with 0 files processed.
Any idea on this? @Simon

Comment: That's probably because you've already copied the file before. Snowflake won't copy a file into a table that has previously been copied. You need to use the force=true option if you want to force it to copy into the table a second time. I've updated my answer with the force=true.

Comment: Ohhh right right. Thank you so muchh <3 <3 <3 @Simon